# Generate base point ( G ) of elliptic curve for elliptic curve cryptography

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

How do I generate a base point or generator for a elliptic curve in Java?

I'm working on developing a Java package that can be used to implement some elliptic curve cryptography algorithms, and I want to use my own curves. However, I'm stuck at the point where I have to get a generator base point for the curve so that I can have the set of domain parameters.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an elliptic curve of "nearly prime" order `u` = `k` `r`, you should:

1. Generate a random point `P`
2. Set `G` = `k` `P`
3. If `G` = 0 goto 1
4. Verify that `r` `G` is not 0 (if it is 0, the curve did not have order `k` `r`).
5. Otherwise G is a point of order `r`.

Comment: Thank you!
Could you clarify once what exactly k and r are? The cardinality or number of points or cofactor? The articles I used to read about elliptic curves used different naming conventions.
From what I figure, k is the order and r is the number of points. Am I right? Also, how do I set G=kP? Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: k*r is the order of the elliptic curve group. r is a large prime, k is small factor. You want a point of order r, and the procedure Rasmus provided gives you one.

Answer (score 1):

this is the same for java, C or whatever....

Let me first assume you created an ECC domain with prime group order q yourself and want to use it for cryptography.
Then select a random x coordinate, then calculate y^2 from the elliptic curve equation in weierstrass form.
Hopefully you selected a prime modulus p which is 3 mod 4. In this case determining the squareroot mod p is trivial if it exists. If it does not exist, try another x. 
I rarely need more than 2 attempts, mostly the first attempt leads to a valid generator already in newly created domains.

You can use my open source program "Academic Signature" for this purpose.
[Manual and link to download page](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~an/crypto/Academic_signature_eng.html).
If you import a new domain into the domain list, you may try an arbitrary generator for this domain. The generator is checked upon import into Academic Signature. If it is not a valid point on the elliptic curve, the x-coordinate of the Test-Point is increased until a valid x y -coordinate pair is encountered. If you subsequently export the domain, the new generator is included in a plaintext file of the domain parameters.

On this page [ECC Domain page](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~an/crypto/accessories/domains_anders.html)you can find some domains I created were I used the above mentioned procedure to get generators containing some "hex wordart".

If you didn't create the domain yourself, if it is of prime order and if you already have a generator used for it in some implementation, it is even easier: Multiply the old implementations generator with a random number and you got yourself a new generator which you can use to separate your keyspace from that of other implementations.

Regards
  Michael Anders