# how to find the best or good enough base point (G) on ECC curve

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

In Elliptic Curve Cryptography, we need a base Point G to generate all other Points aka Public keys.

The order of G must be a prime and should be as large as possible.
Thus, there more private keys for us to choose.

But how can I find a best or good enough G, and how to get the order of G quickly;

order • G = Zero;

For example, on the Secp251k1 curve.

The Order n = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141
the Base Point G.x = 79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B 16F81798

how did the designer of secp251k1 know this?

I found [Generate base point ( G ) of elliptic curve for elliptic curve cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156779/generate-base-point-g-of-elliptic-curve-for-elliptic-curve-cryptography).
It seems the solution is not efficient.

Comment: There is no secp251k1; you appear to mean secp256k1. This is not a programming or development issue; for curves used in crypto it belongs on crypto.SX where it has been answered repeatedly e.g. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43614/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44089/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51350/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58126/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41405/ . More general curves would belong on math or mathoverflow (and I'm not familiar enough to say which).

Comment: However, all of the X9/SECG Fp curves (including secp256k1) were chosen to have prime order, so _all_ rational points are trivially generators. For curves with non-prime but 'nearly' prime order (small cofactor) the method in your linked Q _is_ efficient and is indeed correct.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Where `There`? SECP251k1 seems to be as valid as secp256k1 or secp256r1 (NIST, "recommended", e.g, for TLS).

Comment: @greybeard: secp (and sect) identifiers are assigned by SECG (see SEC2 at secg.org) and they have never assigned 251-bits curves of any kind. NIST curve recommendations apply to ECDSA, and ECDH/MQV since 800-56Ar3, in all uses not just TLS, but TLS _standards_ are set by IETF and 8422 and 8446 now say only P-256,P-384,P-521,X/Ed25519,X/Ed448.